# /sbin/ldconfig: No such file or directory when install paho on mac

Tags: macos, compiler-errors, makefile, mqtt, paho

when I try to install paho step by step referring [Build Paho MQTT c library on Mac OS X](https://www.banym.de/mac/build-paho-mqtt-c-library-on-mac-os-x), error message show as following.

```
Alex:org.eclipse.paho.mqtt.c Alex$ sudo make install
mkdir -p build/output/samples
mkdir -p build/output/test
echo OSTYPE is Darwin
OSTYPE is Darwin
install -m 644  build/output/libpaho-mqtt3c.so.1.0 /usr/local/lib
install -m 644  build/output/libpaho-mqtt3cs.so.1.0 /usr/local/lib
install -m 644  build/output/libpaho-mqtt3a.so.1.0 /usr/local/lib
install -m 644  build/output/libpaho-mqtt3as.so.1.0 /usr/local/lib
install  build/output/MQTTVersion /usr/local/bin
/sbin/ldconfig /usr/local/lib
make: /sbin/ldconfig: No such file or directory
make: *** [install] Error 1
```

Does anyone have any idea about this? Thanks!

[update]

```
Alex:org.eclipse.paho.mqtt.c Alex$ sudo make install
mkdir -p build/output/samples
mkdir -p build/output/test
echo OSTYPE is Darwin
OSTYPE is Darwin
install -m 644  build/output/libpaho-mqtt3c.so.1.0 /usr/local/lib
install -m 644  build/output/libpaho-mqtt3cs.so.1.0 /usr/local/lib
install -m 644  build/output/libpaho-mqtt3a.so.1.0 /usr/local/lib
install -m 644  build/output/libpaho-mqtt3as.so.1.0 /usr/local/lib
install  build/output/MQTTVersion /usr/local/bin
# /sbin/ldconfig /usr/local/lib
ln -s libpaho-mqtt3c.so.1 /usr/local/lib/libpaho-mqtt3c.so
ln -s libpaho-mqtt3cs.so.1 /usr/local/lib/libpaho-mqtt3cs.so
ln -s libpaho-mqtt3a.so.1 /usr/local/lib/libpaho-mqtt3a.so
ln -s libpaho-mqtt3as.so.1 /usr/local/lib/libpaho-mqtt3as.so
install -m 644 src/MQTTAsync.h /usr/local/include
install -m 644 src/MQTTClient.h /usr/local/include
install -m 644 src/MQTTClientPersistence.h /usr/local/include
```

Does it mean that installation is finish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `Makefile` is not OS X ready, especially `install` section. Comment out or delete `ldconfig` line. There is no such command on OS X and it is not needed.

**Update**

As there are more issues, I created a [patch for Makefile](http://pastebin.com/C9Zhq1nq).

Comment: thanks! I did update my question. Does it mean that installation is finish?

Comment: @AlexChang Yes, it is finished

Comment: now I am encountered with another problem! I compile the sample code from [sample](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/clients/c/) and get ld: library not found for -lpaho-mqtt3c
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation).

Comment: @AlexChang I updated my answer. I thought linker would cope with `so` names, but it seems you have to change them into `dylib`.

Comment: @AlexChang If you run into more issues I posted a patch for Makefile.